# Piwik installation on localhost was done, but no login page is shown

Tags: localhost, matomo

I installed piwik on localhost and the Installation was 100% done.
Then i typed www.my-domain/piwik and it just shows me the word piwik with a link to piwik.org.
i don't see the login Page.
What could be wrong? How can i fix it?
Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: My website is based on Typo3 6.1.7, 
my PHP Version is 5.5.10

[image: this is shown when i call piwik]

EDIT2:

I solved this problem.
I just had to add my local IP to the config.ini.php file.
Edit this file with terminal-app...finder does not show this file

```
[General]
trusted_hosts[] = "localhost"
trusted_hosts[] = "192.168.xxx.xxx" <- Your IP Adress
trusted_hosts[] = "127.0.0.1"
trusted_hosts[] = "127.0.0.3"
```

that worked for me

Comment: You should add your solution as an "answer" and then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. I just had to add my local IP to the config.ini.php file. Edit this file with terminal-app...finder does not show this file

```
[General]
trusted_hosts[] = "localhost"
trusted_hosts[] = "192.168.xxx.xxx" <- Your IP Adress
trusted_hosts[] = "127.0.0.1"
trusted_hosts[] = "127.0.0.3"
```

that worked for me